# Trying to override NSView's drawRect from extension class

Tags: swift, overriding, class-extensions

I am designing an NSView class extension in Swift. Inside that extension class, I am trying to override drawRect using this

```
extension NSView {


  override func drawRect(rect: NSRect) {


  }
```

There is an error pointing to the override and saying **Method does not override any method from its superclass... Method drawRect with Objective-C (???) selector 'drawRect' conflicts with the previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector**

What? Objective-C? I am using swift.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *extending* not *subclassing* and then *overriding* a method which was already defined by the *superclass*.

`drawRect` is already defined by `NSView`, that's why the conflict with *already defined ...*

In order to do a custom view you are intended to define your own subclass of `NSView` and override your subclass's `drawRect` implementation.

```
class MyView: NSView {

    override func drawRect(rect: NSRect) {

     // Your custom implementation ....

    } 
}
```

Hope this helps